# Isolating two indexes in a list and summing up one of the indexes with the same indexes as the other?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a text file with the content

```
[100,123,111]
[010,789,222]
[001,123,222]
[230,789,234]
```

I want the sum of the numbers at index 2 which share the same number at index 1. For the above example, the expected output is

```
[333,456]
```

because 111 + 222 = 333 (shared number at index 1: 123) and because 222 + 234 = 456.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Do you have your lists in any kind of collection? In a list or a set?

Comment: @timgeb  The lists are in a .txt file which is opened to read.

Comment: And is the problem how to get these lists read in or how to get the expected result after reading the lists in?

Comment: @timgeb To get the expected results. If I put the desired indexes into it's own lists, I think, I will be able to sum up all the int with the same index in the other list. I'm sorry about my blurry explanation.

Comment: Alright, next time please be more clear about what the problem is, and only ask about the relevant part. It took some follow up questions to find out what you actually want and where you are stuck. I edited your question to make it more clear. Did any of the answers help?

Comment: @timgeb I think I understand that question more now and yes, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's an approach with `ast.literal_eval` and `collections.OrderedDict`.

Let lists.txt be your file with the content

> [100,123,111]
>   [010,789,222]
>   [001,123,222]
>   [230,789,234]

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> with open('lists.txt') as f:
...     d = OrderedDict()
...     for line in f:
...         lst = literal_eval(line)
...         d[lst[1]] = d.get(lst[1], 0) + lst[2]
... 
>>> d.values()
[333, 456]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I'll do more research next time and ask better questions ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I used a defaultdict to shorten the code for adding elements to a dictionary. I just kept a running total with index 1 as the key and then printed out the values

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [[100,123,111],
     [010,789,222],
     [001,123,222],
     [230,789,234]]

d = defaultdict(int)

for i in l:
    d[i[1]] = d[i[1]]+i[2]

print d.values()

[333, 456]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out ^_^

Comment: This assumes that the order of the second elements is always 123,789,123,789,... Is this true? I did not see it in the original question.

Comment: @timgeb yes you are right. I didn't understand that from the original question but I am updating my answer